# Customize address book & contact list

Tags: ios, customization, contacts, addressbook

I'd like to manage contacts from the built-in AddressBook and do the following things:

- Add another section that would come on top (called 'users' for example)
- Put specific contacts (after every single one of them has been treated) in that section.
- Change the action that happens when i select a contact.

I need to show this in the classic peoplepicker, with all the sections ('users', A,B,C) and the correct contacts in them.

Selecting them would execute my code, not simply open details.

Is this at all possible? I haven't really seen anything like that, every guide/sdk/git i see is for the classic contact list and all its usual buttons (add, edit, remove).

Am I missing something obvious? Is it at all possible?